# How to return a different pages in flutter accordingly to specific result?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-layout, firebase-authentication

I have this problem in flutter :
I want to return a different page accordingly to a specific result after doing some functions.
Some functions are asynchronous :

```
home: StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
    if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (ctx, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData)
            {
              return CheckPermission();
            } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return RegistrationPage(); 
          },
      ); // FutureBuilder
    } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return LoginPage();
  },
),// StreamBuilder
```

The getCurrentUser function is async, but the FutureBuilder don't wait to get some data from this function, it continue executing and return the RegistrationPage and after a while the data come to FutureBuilder and then it wants to return the CheckPermission page but the build of RegistrationPage is already beginning so : Error.

If anyone has an idea to solve this.
Thanks.

I tried this to discover the problem :

```
home: StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
    if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (ctx, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData)
            {
              return Text('has Data');
            } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Text('No Data');
          },
      );
    } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return LoginPage();
  },
),
```

I replace the pages by some dummy Text() widgets.
The Text('No Data') is visible and after a while, the Text('has Data') is taking the place instead of Text('No Data').

It means that the function is not waiting for the Data even it's marked with async and wait.

Answer (score 0):

In your FutureBuilder, try adding a ConnectionState check like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            // Add this
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return CheckPermission();
            } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return RegistrationPage();
          },
        ); /
```